# How do you access ward/centroid/median clustering in scipy?

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, hierarchical-clustering

When using `scipy.spatial.distance.pdist` to create a condensed distance matrix and passing it to `ward` and I get this error:

```
Valid methods when the raw observations are omitted are 'single', 'complete', 'weighted', and 'average' error.
```

The documentation though says that the `linkage()` function expects a condensed distance matrix.  How can I work around this problem?

```
foo = np.random.randint(3, size=(10,10))
scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(foo)
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(foo)
bar = scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(foo)
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(bar, method='ward')
```

gives:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy /cluster/hierarchy.py", line 627, in linkage
raise ValueError("Valid methods when the raw observations are "
 ValueError: Valid methods when the raw observations are omitted are 'single', 'complete', 'weighted', and 'average'.
```

I searched a bit and found [this link](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/1798), indicating that a few other people have the problem, but I was unable to find a workaround to provide the data in a form that scipy will accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the docstring:

> y : ndarray
>
> A condensed or redundant distance matrix. A condensed distance matrix is a flat array containing the upper triangular of the distance matrix. This is the form that pdist returns. **Alternatively, a collection of m observation vectors in n dimensions may be passed as an m by n array.**

Passing in your original *observations x dimensions* array `foo` seems to work:

```
scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(foo, method='ward')
```

gives:

```
array([[  1.        ,   2.        ,   2.23606798,   2.        ],
       [  5.        ,   8.        ,   2.23606798,   2.        ],
       [  3.        ,   7.        ,   2.64575131,   2.        ],
       [  9.        ,  11.        ,   2.64575131,   3.        ],
       [  0.        ,  10.        ,   3.31662479,   3.        ],
       [ 12.        ,  13.        ,   3.71483512,   5.        ],
       [  6.        ,  14.        ,   4.12310563,   4.        ],
       [  4.        ,  16.        ,   4.17133072,   5.        ],
       [ 15.        ,  17.        ,   5.5136195 ,  10.        ]])
```

I agree that the documentation for `linkage()` could do with improvement at the very least.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that in the docs.  But I tried to feed my matrix directly in (which is not this toy data, but  a 64x64x53160 matrix), and it didn't work.  The dendrogram that came out from the linkages was not plottable, for instance.

Comment: Your matrix needs to be two-dimensional (i.e. observations x dimensions)

Comment: Right.  In fact, this was not the problem, it was resized into the correct format, but I had made another, incredibly foolish programming error that broke it (using the same variable name for two things(!)).  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage(y, method)` returns correct results for single, complete, average, weighted when y is either a distance matrix or a data matrix. But for centroid, median and ward methods, y has to be a data matrix, error occurs if y is a distance matrix. I agree that the documentation isn't clear.

```
from scipy.cluster.hierarchy import linkage
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

inp = np.loadtxt('iris.txt',delimiter=",", usecols=(0,1,2,3))
x = np.asarray(inp)
Y = pdist(x,'euclidean')
res_linkage = linkage(x,"weighted")`
```

You can test the code above by inputing x a data matrix, or Y an Euclidean distance matrix into the linkage() function.

I also found out that compared to the equivalent implementation in R, `hclust` package, `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` returns different restuls for centroid, median and ward methods. It seems that `scipy.cluster.hierarchy.linkage` contains some errors when updating the distance of a newly merged cluster with an existing cluster.